# "AttributeError: find module" whenever I use "pip" command

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, debian, attributeerror

Whenever I use any command that starts with "pip" (for example: pip --version) I get the following error:

Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
AttributeError: find_module
Error in usercustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
AttributeError: find_module
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in 
from pip import main
AttributeError: find_module

I've tried looking for answers online and some suggest uninstalling pip with the command "pip uninstall pip". This doesn't work for me because again, I cannot run any commands that start with "pip".

I am using Debian 7 if that helps.

Comment: The error message recommends to set `PYTHONVERBOSE`; why don't you set it and get a traceback?

Comment: how do I set PYTHONVERBOSE?

Comment: It's an environment variable. You set it in environment in the shell in the terminal.